# Is it possible to find the criminal with graph-theoretic methods?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

I've been presented to a problem:

> Someone commited a crime. When interrogated, the people, named $G,m,M,J,D$ argued:
>
> - $G:$ It wasn't $D$; It was $M$.
> - $m:$ It wasn't $M$; It wasn't $D$
> - $M:$ It was $D$; It wasn't $G$.
> - $J:$ It was $M$; It was $m$.
> - $D:$ It was $J$; It wasn't $G$.
>
> Knowing that each one of them told a lie, who was the criminal?

I'm pretty sure that graph theoretic methods could be used to solve this problem. I tried to write a graph matrix with $a_{ij}=-1$ if it is said that wasn't him and $a_{ij}=1$ if someone said it was him and $0$ otherwise (I left the $0$ entries null for simplicity), then:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
{}&{G}&{m}&{M}&{J}&{D}\\ 
{G}&{}&{1}&{}&{}&{-1}\\ 
{m}&{}&{}&{-1}&{}&{-1}\\ 
{M}&{-1}&{}&{}&{}&{1}\\ 
{J}&{}&{1}&{1}&{}&{}\\ 
{D}&{-1}&{}&{}&{1}&{}
\end{vmatrix}$$

But I'm unable to find some kind of pattern to solve this problem with this matrix. So, Is there something that could be used to find the criminous with graph-theoretic methods?

Besides this, I've tried to think about matrix permutations assuming that the first proposition of each one is a lie and the second is truth, then the first is truth, then the second is a lie, for example:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
{}&{G}&{m}&{M}&{J}&{D}\\ 
{G}&{}&{1_L}&{}&{}&{-1_T}\\ 
{m}&{}&{}&{-1_L}&{}&{-1}\\ 
{M}&{-1_L}&{}&{}&{}&{1}\\ 
{J}&{}&{1_L}&{1}&{}&{}\\ 
{D}&{-1_L}&{}&{}&{1}&{}
\end{vmatrix}$$

And then permute the $L$ies and $T$ruths to obtain a set of matrices and then find some property on one of these matrices that could indicate who's the criminous. But I also can't see some pattern here.

Answer (score 3):

The problem has no solution. One of the statements *It was M* and *It wasn't M* must be true, so *It wasn't D* must be false. Therefore $D$ is guilty. But then both of $M$'s statements are true.

Comment: There is one way to write a boolean expression to check that, isn't it? I'm just not sure if it would be:

$$\neg d\land m\land \neg m\land \neg d\land d\land \neg g\land m\land M\land j\land \neg g$$

Or

$$(\neg d\land m)\lor (\neg m\land \neg d)\lor (d\land \neg g)\lor (m\land M)\lor (j\land \neg g)$$

Comment: @Voyska: Since you know that at least one statement by each person is false, you know that $$(D\lor\neg M)\land(M\lor D)\land(\neg D\lor G)\land(\neg M\lor\neg m)\land(\neg J\lor G)\;.$$ But $(D\lor\neg M)\land(M\lor D)$ is equivalent to $D\lor(\neg M\land M)$, which is equivalent to $D$. Thus, you have $$D\land(\neg D\lor G)\land(\neg M\lor\neg m)\land(\neg J\lor G)\;,$$ and $D\land(\neg D\lor G)$ implies $D\land G$, making more than one person guilty.

Comment: You wrote $(D\lor\neg M)$ for "*It wasn't $D$; It was $M$*". I'm writing it differently: I'm writing  $(\neg D\lor M)$ for it. Is there a problem with this?

Comment: It seems that writing it the way I'm writing, there are solutions. See [here](http://i.imgur.com/Pj0zinV.png).

Comment: @Voyska: No, I wrote $D\lor\neg M$ to mean *It was D, or it wasn’t M*: remember that at least one of the two statements is **false**. What you’re writing would make sense if you knew that at least one of each person’s statements was **true**. At this point you would do better, I think, to forget about symbolic methods and think about what I wrote in my original answer.

Comment: I agree with Voyska here. The only conclusion you can draw from $G$ and $m$'s statements is that one of them must have told two lies, not that $D$ must be guilty.

Comment: @Leen: The only conclusion that can be drawn is the one that I did draw: the problem, as stated, has no solution.

Comment: "$D$ did it" is consistent with both $G$ and $m$ telling (at least one) lie.

Comment: @Leen: Yes. But as I clearly explained in my answer, and again more formally in my long comment, it is *not* consistent with $M$'s telling at least one lie.

Comment: I was not fighting your final conclusion, I am fighting your argument. It has four sentences. The last part of the second sentence is (at best) premature and definitely suggests that you overlooked the possibility that someone tells two lies. Editing your answer would have been better than adding long comments that try to make it right.

Comment: @Leen: I overlooked nothing. And my long comment says nothing that the original answer does not say; it merely says the same thing more formally. You need to read the argument more carefully. $G$ and $m$ made contradictory statements about $M$; one of them is therefore telling the truth about $M$, and his other statement must be a lie. His other statement is that *It wasn’t D*; therefore it *was* $D$. But then $M$ did not lie, which is impossible. As I said in my answer.

Comment: You are right, I was wrong. I apologize.

Comment: @Leen: That’s okay; I’m just glad that it’s straightened out.

Answer (score 1):

I have read and agree with Scott that there is no solution, but for a different reason.

I do not use graph theory, either. Since there exists one and only one criminal, $G$'s "It was M" has to be a lie, (otherwise both D and M are criminals) which implies that neither D nor M is the criminal. However, since $m$ lies one and only once, either D or M is the criminal. Hence there is a contradiction. The question has no solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think G must have said 'It was m' rather than 'It was M'. That's according to your matrix.

According to J, it must either be m or M. But if it was m, then G is not lying in either of his statements. Then it must be M.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't use any of this matrix stuff. I just simply assumed every statement they made was a lie and for G I constructed the set {D,M'} where M' means M didn't do it. Then for m I have (M, D}. Continuing I have {D', G}, {M', m'}, and {J', G} and conclude that G is the one none of them said did do it therefore G did it.

Comment: No, each one told only one lie.

Comment: It doesn't say each one told only one lie, but I'll work on it assuming that.

Comment: I changed it, but it was what I meant with: *Knowing everyone told a lie, who was the criminal?*.